# Numpy and Pandas Repeat Values by Bin

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe or Numpy array with ascending group numbers, and I would like to assign a list of values (with equal length to the unique number of groups) repeated per group.

```
ID - Group
0  -  0
1  -  0
2  -  1
3  -  1
4  -  1
5  -  2
6  -  2
7  -  3
```

Values to assign:

```
[4, 2, 7, 8] # 4 maps to group 0, 2 maps to group 1 etc
```

Output:

```
ID - Group  - Val
0  -  0     -  4
1  -  0     -  4
2  -  1     -  2
3  -  1     -  2
4  -  1     -  2
5  -  2     -  7
6  -  2     -  7
7  -  3     -  8
```

Appreciate any suggestions, preferably without looping if there are elegant ways/native functions to solve that (looking for both Numpy and Pandas solution).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Setup***:

```
a = np.array([4, 2, 7, 8])
v = df.Group.values
dct = {}
```

---

***Option 1***
Using `numpy` indexing.  (This solution assumes your groups range from `0-N`:

```
dct['numpy_indexing'] = a[v]
```

***Option 2***
Using `np.repeat`. (This solution assumes your groups are not interlaced):

```
dct['numpy_repeat'] = np.repeat(a, np.bincount(v))
```

***Option 3***
Using `map`.  This approach will be slower than the others, but is a bit more flexible, as it allows for interlaced groups and non-linear groups:

```
d = dict(zip(np.unique(v), a))

dct['pandas_map'] = df.Group.map(d)
```

---

***Output***

```
df.assign(**dct)

   ID  Group  numpy_indexing  numpy_repeat  pandas_map
0   0      0               4             4           4
1   1      0               4             4           4
2   2      1               2             2           2
3   3      1               2             2           2
4   4      1               2             2           2
5   5      2               7             7           7
6   6      2               7             7           7
7   7      3               8             8           8
```